# If removeEvent clicked delete from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

JS file this deletes by button the Event

```
        buttons: {
           save : function() {

              calEvent.start = new Date(startField.val());
              calEvent.end = new Date(endField.val());
              calEvent.title = titleField.val();
              calEvent.body = bodyField.val();

              $calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
              $dialogContent.dialog("close");
           },
           "delete" : function() {
               calEvent.id = id;

               $.post("events.php?action=del&id="+calEvent.id);
              $calendar.weekCalendar("removeEvent", calEvent.id);
              $dialogContent.dialog("close");
           },
           cancel : function() {
              $dialogContent.dialog("close");
           }
        }
     }).show();
```

PHP File

```
if($action == 'save')
{
    $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
    $body = $_REQUEST['body'];
    $start_time = (int)$_REQUEST['start'];
    $start_time = $start_time + 60*60;
    $end_time = (int)$_REQUEST['end'];
    $end_time = $end_time + 60*60;
    $start = date('c',$start_time);
    $end = date('c',$end_time);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO meeting_rooms_calendar(title,body,start,end) VALUES ('$title','$body','$start','$end')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

} 
elseif ($action == 'del')
{
    $del = "DELETE FROM `agenda`.`meeting_rooms_calendar` WHERE `meeting_rooms_calendar`.`id` = VALUES ('$id')";
    $result = mysql_query($del, $link);
}
else
{
    $sql= "SELECT id, title, body, 
            DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i' ) AS startTime, DATE_FORMAT(end, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i' ) AS endTime
           FROM meeting_rooms_calendar
           ORDER BY start DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

This wont delete from database, what am I doing wrong to delete it from database?

Comment: try removing `\`` characters

Comment: And try to print $id and tell us what it says

Comment: Sorry where do i need to set the print $id ?

Comment: After: elseif ($action == 'del') {
Do: print $id;

Comment: elseif ($action == 'del'){
 $del = "DELETE FROM `agenda`.`meeting_rooms_calendar` WHERE `meeting_rooms_calendar`.`id` = VALUES ('$id')";
 $result = mysql_query($del, $link);
 print $id;
}

i get empty string "[]"

Comment: i allready get data from events.php like
[{"id":"27","title":"","body":"undefined","start":"2013-11-20T11:15","end":"2013-11-20T11:45"}] this is the save data i need to delete on click

Comment: could you add "print_r($_GET);" before "if($action == 'save')" and tell us what is the output ?

Comment: I get 

Array ( ) [{"id":"27","title":"","body":"undefined","start":"2013-11-20T11:15","end":"2013-11-20T11:45"}]